# How can you preserve type information with variable length Tuples in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm working on an ECS game engine in Typescript. In this project I use a "Signature" which is essentially a set of Classes. The number or types of these classes are not known up front but they all are subclassed from the same class.

A Signature looks something like this:

```
[SerializableClassA, SerializableClassB, SerializableClassC]
```

Signatures are passed into a SignatureManager which has an Iterator returning arrays like this:

```
["entityIDFoo", classAInstance, classBInstance, classCInstance]
```

I'm trying to figure out how to properly define the Signature type in a way that will allow me to properly thread them through a Signature Managers and map the type information to the Iterator output.

Defining a Signature as `SerializableClass[]` makes sense in a lot of ways but doesn't seem to provide a way of mapping the specific class types. Defining them as Tuple `[A, B?, C?, etc..]` seems clunky, hard to use, and potentially wrong given that the exact length is unknown.

I'm currently using an array to represent Signatures but am investigating the performance characteristics of a Set (`Set<SerializableClass>`), so a flexible approach is appreciated.

**Additional Information:**

An extremely simplified version of Signature Manager looks something like the following:

```
class SignatureManager {
    private entityData : TEntityData[];

    constructor (thisSignature : TSignature) {
        this.entityData = getAllEntityDataMatchingSignature(thisSignature);
    }

    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        for (let data of this.entityData) {
            yield data;
        }
    }
}
```

When being used it looks something like this:

```
this.signatureManagerFoo = new SignatureManager([SerializableClassA, SerializableClassB, SerializableClassC]);

for (let [entityID, classAInstance, classBInstance, classCInstance] of this.signatureManagerFoo) {
    // Do stuff in here
    // This is where types need to be automatically threaded through
}
```

Right now using SerializableClass[] as the instance doesn’t do the job because I need to be able to set up generics for SignatureManager so that the variables inside the loop are automatically typed as instances of the classes in the signature that got passed in.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the problem is? In other words, what are you looking for that using `SerializableClass[]` as the definition cannot offer?

Comment: @KarolMajewski I've updated the post with additional information to hopefully narrow down the problem-space.

Comment: I updated my answer. If that doesn't help, please create a minimal, verifiable example in [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your case can be boiled down to:

```
class Sequence<T extends any[]> {
    private sequence: T[];

    constructor(...args: T) {
        this.sequence = [args];
    }

    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        for (let item of this.sequence) {
            yield item;
        }
    }
}

for (let [a, b, c] of new Sequence(42, "foo", true)) {
    /* ... */
}
```

See [TypeScript Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCmBHArvAdseAeAKteAHgC7oAmMYaAngNoC6AfNAN4BQ0H0ADgE4CWANzAloEJKgzwAXNBz0A3K3adgAezQQiPZMCKqeACgB0JsDwDmEGTgCULZZ05EAFnwhGxKdJmgBeaDRmlnSKjgC+So4AVDSwVAC2AEaqIEZ8JDzC+nQGdmyOjgBm+tAGIPBE0Onw8dCqhdAubh7i3vB5DgWOVHzwIKRVJPGhXdAR4awRrMU8peWVgQA00InLwHR1DWjwAO5wrZIGACwATMsARMWq58taqDYdjgD0UdAmRtBRT5NAA).